# Find out Equal row set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, grouping

I have a number of row base on plan and plan detail, I want to find out the same row set with other detail like plan 1 has 3 rows of data in detail table so need to find out the same rows for another plan. I have some sample data with this post may be more helpful to understand my problem. below is the Sample data Image, iwan to group by the record but not on a single row base on the full row set   **base on 
PlanId, MinCount, MaxCount and CurrencyId**

[image]

my expected data is below 
[image]

I had tried to do with Some lengthy process like append all data in a single row and compare with other data, but it seems very lengthy process and takes to much time for 100 records I have an approx 20000 records in an actual database  so not a good solution, please suggest me some thought

Comment: Why will `maxCount` value be 9999 in the second row and 10th row?

Comment: I am sorry for that, I had updated the image, thank you for pointing out unexpected result

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result is rather hard to produce in SQL Server.  The simplest method requires two levels of string concatenation:

```
with t as (
      select a.account_id, 
             stuff( (select '[' +
                            convert(varchar(255), staircount) + ',' +
                            convert(varchar(255), mincount) + ',' +
                            convert(varchar(255), maxcount) + ',' +
                            convert(varchar(255), currencyid) +
                            ']'
                     from t
                     where t.account_id = a.account_id
                     order by staircount
                     for xml path ('')
                    ), 1, 1, '') as details
      from  (select distinct account_id from t) a
     )
select d.details,
       stuff( (select cast(varchar(255), account_id) + ','
               from t
               where t.details = d.details
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as accounts
from (select distinct details from t) d;
```

This isn't exactly your output, but it might be good enough for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This would be trivial in MS Sql Server 2017 by using STRING_AGG.
But in 2012 one of the methods is to use the FOR XML trick.

```
SELECT PlanId, StairCount, MinCount, MaxCount, CurrencyId,
  STUFF((
   SELECT CONCAT(',', t1.AccountId)
     FROM YourTable t1
    WHERE t1.PlanId = t.PlanId
      AND t1.StairCount = t.StairCount
      AND t1.MinCount = t.MinCount
      AND t1.MaxCount = t.MaxCount
      AND t1.CurrencyId = t.CurrencyId
     ORDER BY t1.AccountId
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS AccountIdList
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY PlanId, StairCount, MinCount, MaxCount, CurrencyId
```

Test [here](http://rextester.com/EUI59234)